# How to curve a view edge to looks like an arc

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an view to looks like this:

If there is a way, something like define point A, point B, with a predefined angle.

[image: sample]

The only solution that I found is to make a giant rounded view and insert it as a subview of another view with `clipToBounds = true`. But this has some problems in multiple screen sizes because I'm using constraints.

---

Edit1: After some search, i'm trying to create that view with CAShapeLayer, without success. I'm creating that view by storyboard, with constraints, that view is connected by IBOutlet and your leading constraint too. Here's the code:

On viewDidLoad:

```
self.cnstRoundedLeading.constant = -(self.vwRounded.frame.width/3)
let maskPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: self.vwRounded.bounds.minX*4,
                                                                   y: self.vwRounded.bounds.minY*4,
                                                                   width: self.vwRounded.bounds.width*4,
                                                                   height: self.vwRounded.bounds.height*4),
                                                                    byRoundingCorners: .topLeft,
                                                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.vwRounded.frame.size.width*2,
                                                                                        height: self.vwRounded.frame.size.height))



let maskLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.vwRounded.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    self.vwRounded.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

And on viewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
gradient2.colors = [startColorBlue.cgColor, endColorBlue.cgColor]
gradient2.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
gradient2.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
gradient2.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
vwRounded.applyGradient(gradient2)
```

applyGradient it's a extension of UIView:

```
func applyGradient(_ gradient: CAGradientLayer) -> Void {
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
```

Does not work properly, i don't know the right way to construct that 'arc edge' effect

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. You want a view that looks like a red quarter-circle? That can be accomplished using a view who's content layer is a CAShapeLayer, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Not exactly a quarter-circle, but almost this. A fraction of a circle, i'm not sure what portions of circle is that fraction.

Comment: @RM - show the code you're using to create that arc / shape...

Comment: @DonMag - I'm don't know how create that, what i'm doing is creating a view about to 3x the screen size on storyboard, and adding `self.vwRounded.layer.cornerRadius = self.vwRounded.frame.size.width/2`

But doinging that, i'm having some problems in differents screen size

Comment: @RM - do you want to *display this shape*? Or do you want to mask a view (such as an image view?) *with this shape*?

Comment: @DonMag - I want to mask a view, because this view, with this shape, has a gradient layer.

I edited the question to best explanation of what i want.

Comment: @RM - the best way to create a mask as you have shown is to use a bezier path as a layer mask, and to have it part of a custom class to make it easy to adjust the sizing when the view size changes. You say *"this view, with this shape, has a gradient layer"* ... if you show how you're creating your view with the gradient layer, it will be easier to help you...

Comment: @DonMag - Question properly edited to include my current try to create the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that shape - and use it as a mask - with a `UIBezierPath` (the black border is showing the actual view frame):

[image]

Basically,

- Find the midpoint of the line from `pt1` to `pt2`.
- Find the point perpendicular to that line, with a distance from the line that makes the curve look the way you want. Using the same length as half-the-line-length is what's shown here.
- Create a `UIBezierPath`, connecting `pt1` to `pt2` with a quadratic curve.

Here is example code that you can run directly in a Playground page. I based the `pt1` and `pt2` y-positions based on the image you posted... If you change the frame of the view, it will maintain the proportions you've shown.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override public var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get { return CGSize(width: 800, height: 800) }
        set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
    }

    let myPlainView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let myBorderView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    func customCurvedPath(for rect: CGRect) -> UIBezierPath {

        // curve start point Y is 490/544ths of the height of the view
        let curveStartPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.size.height * 490.0 / 544.0)

        // curve end point Y is 22/544ths of the height of the view
        let curveEndPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height * 22.0 / 544.0)

        var x1 = curveStartPoint.x
        var y1 = curveStartPoint.y

        let x2 = curveEndPoint.x
        let y2 = curveEndPoint.y

        // get the midpoint of the line from x1,y1 to x2,y2
        x1 = (x1 + x2) / 2.0
        y1 = (y1 + y2) / 2.0

        // get the length of half the line (midpoint to endpoint)
        var dx = x1 - x2
        var dy = y1 - y2
        let dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

        // use length of helf the line for distance from line
        // increase or decrease this value to get the desired curve
        let distFromLine = dist

        dx /= dist
        dy /= dist

        // get perpendicular point at distFromLine
        let x3 = x1 - (distFromLine/2)*dy
        let y3 = y1 + (distFromLine/2)*dx

        let curveControlPoint = CGPoint(x: x3, y: y3)

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()

        // pt1
        myBezier.move(to: curveStartPoint)

        // quad curve to pt2
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: curveEndPoint, controlPoint: curveControlPoint)

        // line to pt3 (bottom right corner)
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))

        // line to pt4 (bottom left corner)
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.height))

        // close the path (automatically add a line from bottom left corner to curve start point)
        myBezier.close()

        return myBezier

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let vwWidth = CGFloat(710.0)
        let vwHeight = CGFloat(544.0)

        view.addSubview(myBorderView)

        myBorderView.backgroundColor = .clear

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            myBorderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: vwWidth + 2.0),
            myBorderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: vwHeight + 2.0),
            myBorderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myBorderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

            ])

        myBorderView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

        // comment this next line (or set to false) to see the actual view frame
        myBorderView.isHidden = true

        view.addSubview(myPlainView)

        myPlainView.backgroundColor = .red

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            myPlainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: vwWidth),
            myPlainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: vwHeight),
            myPlainView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myPlainView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

            ])

        let bezPath = customCurvedPath(for: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vwWidth, height: vwHeight))

        // add the bezier path as a layer mask
        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = bezPath.cgPath
        myPlainView.layer.mask = maskForPath

    }

}

let viewController = TestViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

As I mentioned, this would work better as part of a custom view class, as you could override `layoutSubviews()` to keep the path shape consistent.

Here's an example using a gradient layer + a layer mask in a custom view, set to `300 x 250`:

[image]

And the Playground-runnable source:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class MaskedGradientView: UIView {

    var gradLayer: CAGradientLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        gradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor]
        gradLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        layer.addSublayer(gradLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let rect = self.bounds

        gradLayer.frame = self.bounds

        // curve start point Y is 490/544ths of the height of the view
        let curveStartPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.size.height * 490.0 / 544.0)

        // curve end point Y is 22/544ths of the height of the view
        let curveEndPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height * 22.0 / 544.0)

        var x1 = curveStartPoint.x
        var y1 = curveStartPoint.y

        let x2 = curveEndPoint.x
        let y2 = curveEndPoint.y

        // get the midpoint of the line from x1,y1 to x2,y2
        x1 = (x1 + x2) / 2.0
        y1 = (y1 + y2) / 2.0

        // get the length of half the line (midpoint to endpoint)
        var dx = x1 - x2
        var dy = y1 - y2
        let dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

        // use length of helf the line for distance from line
        // increase or decrease this value to get the desired curve
        let distFromLine = dist

        dx /= dist
        dy /= dist

        // get perpendicular point at distFromLine
        let x3 = x1 - (distFromLine/2)*dy
        let y3 = y1 + (distFromLine/2)*dx

        let curveControlPoint = CGPoint(x: x3, y: y3)

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()

        // pt1
        myBezier.move(to: curveStartPoint)

        // quad curve to pt2
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: curveEndPoint, controlPoint: curveControlPoint)

        // line to pt3 (bottom right corner)
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))

        // line to pt4 (bottom left corner)
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.height))

        // close the path (automatically add a line from bottom left corner to curve start point)
        myBezier.close()

        // add the bezier path as a layer mask
        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = myBezier.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskForPath

    }

}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override public var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get { return CGSize(width: 400, height: 400) }
        set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
    }

    let myMaskedGradientView: MaskedGradientView = {
        let v = MaskedGradientView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let myPlainView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(myMaskedGradientView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            myMaskedGradientView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            myMaskedGradientView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250.0),
            myMaskedGradientView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myMaskedGradientView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

            ])

    }

}

let viewController = TestViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what i want, some small changes to adapt to my code, and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot.